# React Native fetch/axios GET request 403 error but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, react-native, get, fetch-api, http-status-code-403

```js
fetch("http://localhost/user/shop", {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Hello, everyone.  I'm getting a 403 forbidden request error from calling an API from a local backend server.  The API call works in Postman flawlessly but for some reason, when I use a fetch/axios GET request in React Native to call the API, it does not work and keeps giving me that 403 error.  Does anybody have a solution for this?  All I'm doing is just a simple GET request that shouldn't require any authorization details or anything.  Below are screenshots of the error and the Postman request:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure.  Please see my above edited post with screenshots. :)

Comment: Where is the react-native app running? If it's on a device that is not the same host as the backend server, you will need to use the network address of the server, not `localhost`

Comment: FYI, GET requests do not require a content-type header since they have no request body. You also seem to be double JSON encoding the `data` in the response which you probably don't want to do

Comment: The react-native app is running on http://localhost:19006 through Expo.  My Java Spring backend is running on http://localhost:80

Comment: @StanleyYeung but what device is running the react-native app? Is it on your phone or are you opening the web version in your PC browser?

Comment: Okay.  I just added a screenshots of my React Native app from Visual Studio Code and headers from Postman. :)

Comment: @Phil It's running on my laptop.  So yes, it's web version.

Comment: Your Postman request appears to include a session cookie. Are you sure you're not using any authentication?

Comment: Thanks, Phil! I called the API using Expo app on my phone and it worked! :) (I entered the IP instead of localhost)